# queueing package R -> M/M/c queue: how to model machine-repair queueing system, but only allow #servers down-events?

Tags: r, queueing

M/M/c allows for modeling of c servers (in my case: repair men). Via lambda (arrival rate) I generate the arrival of events (in my case: failures that are triggered by some machines).
This means that the max. number of failures-events in the system is equal the number of machines that trigger them. (this means that there cannot be generated a failure event if there are machines already broken ...).
Question: Basic MMC() function in queueing package does not consider this max number! How can I implement it? Thanks.

```
mmc <- NewInput.MMC(lt,m,i) # (arrivalRate, serviceRate, resources)
      mmcQueue <- QueueingModel(mmc)
```

Here: arrivalRate shall only generate arrivals (of failures) if a certain number (#machines that trigger the failures) is not exceeded.

Answer (score 0):

Would this not be a finite-source system, M/M/c/c/m, where c = number of repairmen and c = maximum number of failures allowed in the system, and m = number of machines?

You could use the following function from the package:

```
NewInput.MMCKM(lambda=0, mu=0, c=1, k=1, m=1, method=0)
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried this as well with k=m (i.e., M/M/c/k/k). BUT: I then struggle with some parameter settings, where the "k" needs to be greater than the "c", i.e. number of machines (failures)/queue length > number of repairmen c. I do not know why this constraint is necessary. The utilization of other (c-k) repairman shall simply switch to -infinity or alike, indicating that they would be idle. In my real case k=m=47 and c=7 to 15 maximum. So I do not have this issue of k<m ...